# Screen frozen after booting, cant get to tty, backgroundimage not loaded, mouse, keyboard do not work

Tags: 20.04, kde

I had a running Ubuntu with KDE. Now when I start, I get to the desktop (I do not need to login) but:

- taskbar, etc. loads but no background image
- mouse is stuck in the middle of the screen
- cant do anything with the keyboard
- cant access tty

I restarted into recovery mode, got to root shell and removed nvidia packages. Then run startx. Same behaviour. Booting into recovery mode and just run resume leads to the same situation.

A few days before I cloned the hard drive from a HDD to a SSD. But I could use the system after that without issues.

Do I need to reinstall the OS?

Similar to [Upgrade to 20.04, mouse and keyboard don't work - any idea how I fix this?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1265981/970062) but recovery mode + resume does **not** work.

Comment: Personally I would re install. That is always the safest thing to do with new hardware.

Comment: You may be bitten by [bug#1939638](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1939638) which prevents activation of USB devices during boot. To verify, try unplugging and replugging your keyboard and mouse after you see the desktop and check whether they start working.